# hard drive issue backup files in chunks?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup

Im on windows 7 and my hard drive is dying. I can backup the smaller files, however, when backing up larger files the HD stops working half way through. I have to restart the hard drive (usb) and then it works again.

I think the drive is overheating, or there is a problem with warped head/platters.

My question is (since I can only back up small files (less than 500mb or so) is it possible to copy a file off in chunks (ie 100mb increments), so that when the hd dies I can just resume where I left off?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries I found the solution with teracopy http://codesector.com what an amazing program!